# Javascript with datalist won't display all matched options

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

Some options from `<template>` did not show in `<datalist>`. Using the code below, I tried to key in "ray " but it only shows "ray AA". When I tried to type "ray b", it shows "Ray BB". Is there something wrong with the code. please let me if there is any workaround for this issue. thanks.

```js
        var search = document.querySelector('#search');
        var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults'); 
        var templateContent = 
        document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;
        search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
        while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
            var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
            var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(templateContent.cloneNode(true).children, function searchFilter(frag, item, i) {
                if (inputVal.test(item.textContent) && frag.children.length < 6) frag.appendChild(item);
                    return frag;
            }, document.createDocumentFragment());
            results.appendChild(set);
        });
```

```html
    <template id="resultstemplate">
        <option>Ray AA</option>
        <option>Ray BB</option>
        <option>Ray1</option>
        <option>Ray2</option>
    </template>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type 'r'" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="searchresults"></datalist>

    <script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

When the user type "ray ", both "Ray AA" and "Ray BB" must show.

Answer (score 1):

Using cloneNode on item seems to be working.

```js
        var search = document.querySelector('#search');
        var results = document.querySelector('#searchresults'); 
        var templateContent = 
        document.querySelector('#resultstemplate').content;
        search.addEventListener('keyup', function handler(event) {
        while (results.children.length) results.removeChild(results.firstChild);
            var inputVal = new RegExp(search.value.trim(), 'i');
            var set = Array.prototype.reduce.call(templateContent.cloneNode(true).children, function searchFilter(frag, item, i) {
                if (inputVal.test(item.textContent) && frag.children.length < 6) frag.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true));
                    return frag;
            }, document.createDocumentFragment());
            results.appendChild(set);
        });
```

```html
    <template id="resultstemplate">
        <option>Ray AA</option>
        <option>Ray BB</option>
        <option>Ray1</option>
        <option>Ray2</option>
    </template>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type 'r'" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="searchresults"></datalist>

    <script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

**Reason**

appendChild moves the node completely. So, when the reduce iteration takes place, the nodes are moved when `appendChild()` is called. Thus, the length of the original list is reduced. Cloning the node before appending fixes this issue.

Comment: How would you make the dropdown dissapear after Enter or Mouse click? It stays after the seleciton.